# DRY up - Call class method if no instance exists, otherwise call instance method

Tags: javascript, class, instance, dry

**Situation**

If input is a "start", automatically calculate the "end" and then prefill the page with the "end"

If input is a "end", simply prefill the page with it

I'm trying to write a class to handle this functionality.

```
class EndVal(start_value) {
  constructor() {
    this.end_value = start_value + 10
    $("#end").text(this.end_value)
  }

  static prefill(end_value) {
    $("#end").text(end_value)
  }
}
```

Based on the above code if what you have is a "start", you'd just do `new EndVal(start_value)`, but if you already have an "end" rather than instantiating a new object, you can just do `EndVal.prefill(end_value)`. But it isn't very DRY... I'm wondering how to fix it, and somehow link the instance and class methods?

Comment: hm. the only thing not "DRY" about this, is the jQuery `text()` call. If you put that in its own function, it would become "DRY", but i doubt that's what you're asking. Could you clarify? What am i missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `prefill` method should use the passed argument instead of `this`. Now you can all the method from the constructor:

```js
class EndVal {
  constructor(start_value) {
    this.end_value = start_value + 10
    this.constructor.prefill(this.end_value);
  }

  static prefill(end_value) {
    console.log(end_value);
  }
}

const endVal = new EndVal(15);

EndVal.prefill(28);
```